# could the ctcdecode be serialized and executed in non-Python environments, such as torchscript?

Tags: pytorch, torchscript, torchaudio

https://pytorch.org/audio/master/generated/torchaudio.models.decoder.CTCDecoder.html implementes ctc decoder.

could the ctcdecode be serialized and executed in non-Python environments, such as torchscript?